# How to remove a decorative glass window pane?

Tags: windows

Previous owners installed decorative panes over double-paned windows, which have since fogged. These are **not** mullions. They appear to have a black caulk holding them in place.

I'm told I can remove them myself (by the folks at Renewal Anderson), but I don't know where to start. They are not an Anderson product; they were put on after the original Anderson windows were installed.

Any advice for what to try? What to research? I keep finding DIY on removing mullions, etc., but not these particular after-market additions.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Usually You need to take off the wood trim around the inside of the glass. Then there is caulking that must be cut or trimmed and the glass can be removed.

Comment: Clearer, more detailed/close-in pictures would help. From this vantage is looks exactly the same as cling-film window-overlay with leading, whcih just peels off. It also looks like there are screens or storm windows clipped in, which should be unclipped & removed to make the detailed pictures showing the actual thing you want to remove clearer.

Comment: Thank you -- adding more photos now!

Comment: If you know they're Andersen, there are probably instructions on the company website. At a guess, I'd say carefully free/extract the black caulking (preferably without scratching the frame), but that is only a guess based on minimal information.

Comment: With new pics, it appears the aftermarket panel was inserted and just caulked in place.  You will obviously have to cut/ remove the caulk along the edges of the frame.  This does not look like an easy task. The other option may be to call a window repair company and get an estimate for them to do the removal.  Especially since the fogged glass needs replacing.

Comment: Yep -- I started picking at it and it's just a pane caulked in place. I think I could remove it, but I wouldn't want to damage the double-pane window underneath it. Advice? When I search for DIY tips on this topic, I get videos for removing windows, but not just the pane.

Comment: Just carefully remove as much of the caulk as possible.  Then gently try to pry the panel out.  Wear eye and skin protection in case the glass breaks.  There is no way to tell if any caulk is holding the panel to the original window, so it will be a surgical removal process.  You just need to be patient and work at it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll give it a try -- with eye and skin protection. I appreciate it!

Comment: Are you wanting to remove them so you can put them back after replacing the glazing?  If they're only caulked on, you may be able to use a razor scraper to scrape under the caulk.

Comment: No, no replacing. The glazing, I'm told, is probably what caused the fogging in the first place -- warming the pane and causing separation, allowing moisture in. I just want to get back to clear windows again, without the after-market additions.